# Javascript Canvas Serialization/Deserialization?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can you serialize/deserialize a canvas object in javascript?

Answer (score 16):

Besides the `getImageData` method, you can use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get an data-URL-encoded PNG. If you need to serialize to a string, it would save having to convert the raw data to a string manually. You could deserialize by creating an image and setting the src to the data URL, then drawing it to a canvas.

[Edited to account for asynchronous loading (suggested by olliej).]

```
function serialize(canvas) {
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function deserialize(data, canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };

    img.src = data;
}
```

If I remember correctly, some older versions of Safari, and maybe Opera didn't support `toDataURL`, but the more recent versions do.

Comment: Technically the image is not guaranteed to be loaded synchronously so you should really do the remainder of the work in the images onload handler

Answer (score 5):

You can get direct pixel access with canvas.getImageData() and .putImageData(). You can also serialize images to a data URL with canvas.toDataURL() for posting to a server.

This only works in newer browsers.