# Saving an html object to firebase

Tags: javascript, canvas, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm working in ember.js my project has an image cropping mechanic. This returns to me by default a canvas object and some data necessary to redraw the cropped image.

But when I try to save the canvas object to firebase it saves it as something like `[htmlObject Canvas]` or something like that, so when I try to get the record and display the canvas it displays that instead of the actual canvas object.

How can I save a canvas object to firebase to use later as an actual canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to serialize and deserialize the image:

```
function serialize(canvas) {
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function deserialize(data, canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };

    img.src = data;
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766451/901944).

### Update 1

The `canvas.toDataURL()` method is able to compress the data into JPEG with compression. Using even 95% quality will drastically decrease filesize for photos, compared to PNG.

Use this:

```
canvas.toDataURL({
   format: 'jpeg',
   quality: 0.9
});
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30534427/901944).

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I'm doing now but the DataURL is so large it takes a while to resolve from the server. So now I'm thinking I may need to come up with a different solution to make that process a bit faster

Comment: Dear Jordan, but it's a totally different question! It's neither related to Ember nor to Firebase. Please accept this answer as it resolves the original problem, and start a new question about image compression.